# Angular ajax file upload not catching 500 HTTP response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to catch `500` errors from a file upload, but I cannot seem to do so. I have tried adding multiple types of catches in the code but none have worked.

This is the main upload method in my service:

```js
    private uploadFile(endpoint: string, uploadModel: UploadFileModel): Observable<number | null> {
        uploadModel.formData.append('file', uploadModel.file);
        return this._httpClient
            .post(endpoint, uploadModel.formData, {
                reportProgress: true,
                observe: 'events'
            }).pipe(map(event => {
                switch (event.type) {
                    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                        const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total) / 100;
                        uploadModel.progress = progress;
                        return progress;
                    case HttpEventType.Response:
                        console.log('response', event.body);
                        return event.body;
                }
            })) as Observable<number | null>;
    }
```

I then call it like so:

```js
const subscription = this._presentationService
    .uploadFile(endPoint, model)
    .subscribe({
        next: res => {
            if (typeof res === 'number' && res >= 1) {
                this.presentationFile.step++;
                this.presentationFile.progress = 0;
                subscription.unsubscribe();
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('res', res);
            }
            return this.setStepComplete(false);
        },
        error: err => console.log('err', err),
        complete: () => console.log('complete')
    });
```

Whenever a `500` is created all that gets printed to the console is the following:

[image: Console]

I am trying to catch these `500` errors to display an error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you have an erroneous `{` in the subscribe.

Try:

```
const subscription = this._presentationService
    .uploadFile(endPoint, model)
    .subscribe(res => { // !! change here !!
            if (typeof res === 'number' && res >= 1) {
                this.presentationFile.step++;
                this.presentationFile.progress = 0;
                subscription.unsubscribe();
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('res', res);
            }
            this.setStepComplete(false); // this return is unnecessary, can't return in subscribe block.
        },
        (error: err) => { 
                        console.log('In error !!'); 
                        console.log('err', err); 
        },
        () => console.log('complete') // make sure you see complete.
    });
```

Comment: What I have is valid syntax, we use it everywhere else in the code, however, I will give it a try...

Comment: Actually you are right, you are destructuring. Can you add a log into the `map` in the service and make sure it isn't logged on errors. I also see in your log for error 'res' which means it took the non error route.

Comment: Two events are output: 0 and 1 (Sent and UploadProgress)

Comment: That's interesting, it shouldn't go into the map for an error response.

Comment: Those values are before the error since we are watching the progress

Comment: So, the error event itself isn't going into the map.

Comment: But it doesn't come into the `error` callback of the `subscribe`?

Comment: I am not sure then, sorry :/

Comment: I seemed to have figured something out, but I'm not sure if it is the best solution. See my answer if your interested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can catch the error by attaching a `subscription` and a `pipe` to the post object without chaining.

The issue here is that I do not get the body of the response, as it comes back empty.

```
const client = this._httpClient
    .post(endpoint, uploadModel.formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
    });

client.subscribe({
    error: error => console.log('error', error)
});

return client.pipe(map(event => {
    switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total) / 100;
            uploadModel.progress = progress;
            return progress;
    }
})) as Observable<number | null>;
```